# Why does not Datepicker work?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

All,

I have this page,

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="priceLists.aspx.cs" Inherits="PriceWorx.priceLists" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css"
        rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs({ collapsible: true });

            $("#tabs").tabs({ event: "mouseover" });     
            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                minDate: "0",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true

            });

        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <!-- all tabs -->
    <div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <!-- tab definitions -->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1" class="dynamic">foo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">bar</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1" style="width: 100%;">
            <div>
                <p>
                    Date:
                    <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tr valign="top" align="center">
                    <td style="width: 100%;" colspan="4">
                        bar
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Tabing works fine , but not the Datepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of jQuery UI is 1.8.9. Just change this line:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/9XC67/

Answer (score 2):

Not enough info to know why this is broken. I  can walk you though how i would debug this..

- open firebug console. are there any errors?
- using firebug look at the bottom of the body tag and see if the datapicker hidden div exists there.
- if the div exists, using firebug set display to block from hidden. do you see the datepicker? switch to different tabs and try this process.
- it could be that the datepicker is behind something, hide all the tabs in firebug and make the datepicker visible

Comment: I have to disagree here. He provided all the necessary markup to demonstrate why it is broken. I can copy everything except the Page Directive into a new .html file and replicate his problem.

Comment: datepicker is visibkle as simple text input field.. but not as a calander.. Thanks

Comment: fair enough, but i couldnt tell why it was broken by simply looking at it, and i am not paid enough to do anything more

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with this line in your head. Remove it and it seems to work.

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" 
  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

You're pulling the wrong css. Change it to be 1.8.0 theme and it'll work.

Or you can change the javascript reference as Shane pointed out.

Comment: Thanks - Upvodted, changing js  to 1.8.9  as Shane suggested too work.